# webpack packing website and upload to ipfs but node_modules not found

Tags: dapps, ipfs

After webpacking the website, I upload the dist folder to ipfs. The ethereum part is working fine, however no js files (except for app.js) and node modules can be found. But as you can see in the pics, they are right there.
[image]
[image]

When I use "npm run dev" to run the website, everything is working fine.
I'm new to this, can somebody help me T T
I directly use ipfs hash to open the website without any server. Is it the reason cause this situation?

here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: "./src/javascripts/app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "app.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: "./src/index.html", to: "index.html" },
      { from: "./src/views/userHomepage.html", to: "userHomepage.html" },
      { from: "./src/views/userInfo.html", to: "userInfo.html" },
      { from: "./src/views/editBlog.html", to: "editBlog.html" },
      { from: "./src/views/newBlog.html", to: "newBlog.html" },
      { from: "./src/views/blog.html", to: "blog.html" },
      { from: "./src/views/tag.html", to: "tag.html" }
    ]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      ETHEREUM_NODE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.ETHEREUM_NODE_URL),
      IPFS_API_HOST: JSON.stringify(process.env.IPFS_API_HOST),
      IPFS_API_PORT: JSON.stringify(process.env.IPFS_API_PORT),
      IPFS_GATEWAY_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.IPFS_GATEWAY_URL)
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2)$/, use: 'url-loader' }
    ]
  },
  devServer: { 
    //contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"), compress: true 
    port:8000,
  },
};
```